# how to shutdown a laptop using remote command?

Tags: command-line, mac, laptop, remote-shutdown

What if I want to shutdown a MacBook using another brand laptop what process should I do? (remotely using the cmd)

Is it possible or it has to be MacBook cause I'm using Toshiba?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options, depending what you have installed, or are willing to install:-

1. Use [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/) or other remote desktop software on both machines: this allows you to log in remotely, and you can then shut down as if you were sitting at the laptop (TeamViewer is free for non-commercial use).
2. Run `ssh` from the remote PC and type `sudo shutdown -h now`.
3. Run a background script which periodically checks for the presence of a flag file on a shared directory: if found, the script deletes the flag file, then runs `shutdown -h now`; since `sudo cannot be used non-interactively, the script must be started in a root shell.

   - The deletion of the flag file indicates to the remote PC that the shut-down command has been executed.
   - The script should delete the flag file when it first runs, to stop the laptop shutting down immediately on reboot, in case it was already shut down when the flag file is set.

Other forms of shut-down can be invoked with different commands (`sudo pmset ...`), such as sleep or hibernation.

Comment: Note that `sudo shutdown -h now` will not perform a very clean shutdown (e.g. you may lose unsaved changes in documents). A GUI-based shutdown (TeamViewer, VNC, etc) is better.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Absolutely. Though I did not explicitly say so, I ordered my solutions by preference, and incidentally reverse order of the amount that would need to be installed. You were quite right to mention other remote desktop software, and I have modified my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

No, it isn't possible. You would need 2 Toshibas or 2 MacBooks. Windows which is most likely on your Toshiba uses the command prompt to interpret batch commands, which can only affect Windows remote computers. There may be an application to do this, but I don't know of any.

For future reference, the command to shutdown computers remotely on Windows is: `shutdown -i`.